# Warning: failed to set breakpoint site ... error sending the breakpoint request

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error when I completely exit the app and then trying to reopen it. This is only happening on iOS after I upgraded to React Native version 0.54.2. Any guesses as to why this could be happening? It's seriously impeding my workflow as I have to run the app all over again because it effectively prevents the app from starting up again..

```
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x238c0584 for breakpoint -3.1: error sending the breakpoint request
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x238c0894 for breakpoint -3.2: error sending the breakpoint request
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x238c027c for breakpoint -3.3: error sending the breakpoint request
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x238cedf0 for breakpoint -4.1: error sending the breakpoint request
```